# varnish 503 service unavailable

Tags: caching, varnish, varnish-vcl, http-status-code-503

My varnish version is `3.0`.

My server works well while I curl the URLs, but when use varnish cache it return `503 service unavailable` occasionally.

The log info likes is:

```
0 Debug        - "VCL_error(200, OK)"
24 VCL_call     c recv error
24 VCL_call     c error deliver
24 SessionClose c error
0 Debug        - "VCL_error(200, OK)"
27 VCL_call     c recv error
27 VCL_call     c error deliver
27 SessionClose c error
0 Debug        - "VCL_error(200, OK)"
16 VCL_call     c recv error
16 VCL_call     c error deliver
16 SessionClose c error
14 Debug        - "Write error, retval = 2998272, len = 8465870, errno = Success"
0 Debug        - "VCL_error(200, OK)"
14 VCL_call     c recv error
14 VCL_call     c error deliver
14 SessionClose c error
0 Debug        - "VCL_error(200, OK)"
21 VCL_call     c recv error
21 VCL_call     c error deliver
21 SessionClose c error
```

PS:The server response 200 when I curl or type the urls on browsers.

Comment: VCL tag is for delphi use. Please use varnish-vcl instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

varnish 503 can be fixed by steps below:

1. Increase the `connect_timeout`,`.first_byte_timeout` and `.between_bytes_timeout` in you backend setting:

   ```
   backend default {
     .host = "www.example.com";
     .connect_timeout = 5s;
     .first_byte_timeout = 10s;
     .between_bytes_timeout = 10s;
   }
   ```
2. Increase the parameter to 8192 when start varnish.

   ```
   varnishd [options] http_resp_hdr_len=8192
   ```
3. Checkout you `network` or `backend server`.

   If Step 1 and Step 2 can not help you, please check you `network connection` and `banckend server's availability`.

Comment: Maybe this will help others too: i had a similar problem with curl and varnish. Also got the annoying 503 with curl requests while the rest responded normally. My fix: removed the "Content-Length" header (as i had it just to be complete)

Comment: From my reading https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishd.html  32bit systems should be accounted for with regard to #2 option above. Also, the default value seems to be 8192 ?

Comment: @barthoda most likely the first_byte_timeout if I were to guess.